# Multiple views sharing same OnClickListener -- listen one at a time?

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I'm working on a tile memory game.

A user can press any one of the tiles on a 9x9 board.

However, I want to limit the user to being only to press one at a time.

I've tried researching using a TableLayout, setting beforeAscendants=true, and having that try to manage where a user's click goes, but that proves tedious and saving all those coordinates seems inefficient to the possibility of an easier solution existing.

Right now, I call .setOnClickListener on each of those tiles and setting them to the same onClickListener, but there's no way to limit how many tiles can be pressed at once. I've tried A) setting a synchronized() section around the code inside the anonymous onClickListener code, B) having a boolean to set to true if one tile is already in the onClickListener code but it's simply ignored and C) banging my head against the wall, didn't help

Thanks!

Comment: Option B should work very well for this type of thing, so it must be something with your code. Can you show us what you've tried? Also, from experience, option C ends up with a hospital trip and/or concussion and, I may be wrong, but I don't think it would solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

This is the most straightforward and simplest way I can come out with. You should optimize the logic too, it's pretty lengthy here.

```
onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.tile1:
        // Tile 1 is clicked
        // Disable other tiles (try setClickable(false))
            break;
        ...
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```